# What happens if I delete the swapfile in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, files, swap

Running out of disk space and trying to free memory. Saw that this took up 2gb, curious what happens if I delete this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible reduce swap memory size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163554/is-it-possible-reduce-swap-memory-size)

Comment: @Muzaffar The linked question title looks promising but the answers only speak about changing the swap _partition_ size or swappiness. Neither probably helps with reducing the size of swap _file_.

Comment: You will break your system if you delete the 2GB swap partition without telling the system to stop using it. This is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @waltinator thank you for the reply. This was the answer I wanted to hear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. It's not possible to delete a swap file that's in use.